# Response validation using only certain words in Google Forms

Tags: regex, validation, google-forms

I have a Google Forms with the question "What is your name?" and the answer specified to be *Short answer*. However I want to allow only certain answers like Tom or Peter.

I know in this easy case I could use a *Drop-down* instead and put in the names as options. But in reality I have a long list of valid answers which would be too long for a *Drop-down*. I want to rather use the *Response validation* feature combined with *Regular expressions* to check if the answer is either Tom or Peter. So I want a correct answer to be `Tom` or `Peter` but nothing like `Tom Peter` and nothing else like `Tree`.

I tried to set *Regular Expression Contains* `("Tom"|"Peter")` but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Don't use the double quotes inside your regex., it should be: (Tom|Peter)

Comment: @PoulBak Thanks, that seems to work. However also Tom Peter and Peter46 works.

Comment: Try: ^(Tom|Peter)$ - This Means start and end of string.

Comment: That works. Thanks so much!